# Modifying php.ini file from command line without using editor

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I want to change the value of allow_url_fopen = Off, in php.ini file using terminal Commands without using any editor.

Is there any command to do that?
My php.ini file is at /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: `# sed 's/allow_url_fopen = Off/allow_url_fopen = On/g' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini && service apache2 restart`

Comment: @tilz0R i am writing a bash script for drupal installation.

Comment: @Timurib sed did worked for me. I modified it a little and it worked.

sed -i 's/allow_url_fopen\s*=.*/allow_url_fopen=Off/g' /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\(allow_url_fopen\).*/\1 = On/' -i /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

in case the `allow_url_fopen` or any other key may have a commented out sign (";") you can use:

```
sed 's/^;\?\(allow_url_fopen\).*/\1 = On/' -i /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```